# How to access parent data in JsViews data-linked method

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

Is it possible to access parent data from within a data-linked function in JsViews?

```
{^{for sections}}
...
{^{for itemTypes}}
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>{^{:label}}</td>
        <td>{^{if addable==true}}<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-link="{on ~addItem}">Add an item</button>{{/if}} </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
{{/for}}
...
{{/for}}
```

Is it possible to access the section data (the parent) from the addItem function?

```
 addItem: function(ev, eventArgs) {
   var view = eventArgs.view;
   var index = view.getIndex();
   var parent = ????
   ...
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs provide relevant information in a few places, such as:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@parent
- http://www.jsviews.com/#views@parent-data
- http://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@get
- http://www.jsviews.com/#views

For programmatic access within the addItem method, you can use view APIs to step up through the view hierarchy, then get the data:

```
var section = view.parent.parent.data;
```

or

```
var section = view.parent.get("item").data;
```

Alternatively you can pass the section data down declaratively as a contextual parameter:

```
{^{for itemTypes ~section=#data}}
...
<button ... data-link="{on ~addItem ~section}">
```

then use it directly:

```
addItem: function(section, ev, eventArgs) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Boris.  Such a thorough answer and the perfect solution(s).  I'll be sure to read through the docs in more detail now!